# Expected value of exp(X)

Tags: definite-integrals, stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value

I trying to prove that something is finite. I have given that $\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{X}\right]$ is finite and I am supposed to show that:
$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}e^zP(X>z)dz$
is finite. I tried applying Markov's inequality which led me to:
$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}e^zP(X>z)dz=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}e^zP(e^X>e^z)dz\leq \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{X}\right]dz$
but that doesn't work out. Someone has a clue how to do it?

Thank you to everyone that contributes.

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: Just calculate $E[e^X]$ by formula $E[Y] = \int P(Y>t)dt$, $Y\geq 0$ and substitute for the integral.

Comment: The trick is to show that $E[e^X] = \int e^z P(X> z) dz$.

Comment: Thanks. Very stupid of me. Didn‘t even think about the possibility to view $e^X$ as a nonnegative RV.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is quite heuristic, but with a little work it could be made rigorous. Let $F(x)=P(X\le x)$  and $G(x)=1-F(x)$.  $E(e^X)=\int_Re^xdF(x)$.  Integrate by parts to get $E(e^X)=e^xF(x)]_R-\int_R e^xF(x)dx=e^xF(x)]_R+\int_Re^x(G(x)-1)dx=e^x(F(x)-1)]_R+\int_Re^xG(x)dx$.  Since $F(\infty)=1$ and $e^{-\infty}=0$ we have $E(e^X)=\int_Re^xG(x)dx$.

Obviously using $F(\infty)=1$ may not be enough.  We need $\lim_{x\to \infty} e^x(1-F(x))$ finite. .This probably can be derived form $E(e^X)$ being finite